# Fastest method to design on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, web-services

I need to dynamically draw with javascript on one webpage 4000 rectangles, I tried with `divs`, `SVG` and `canvas` but the biggest problem is to resize the page, because I must redraw the wole page and it could take up to 5 seconds.

Which is the fastest method to design rectangle on one webpage?

**EDIT:**

I have two table like this one

[image: base state]

when the 'images' are designed the scroll of the page is pretty good, but the problem is when I must resize the wole page to fit the window size.

In real time I must change the pictures in base of some data recived a this is an example of the result

[image: end state]

You can see that the inside image of every rectangle is not the same so I can't only change the color of that.

Now I have 75 columns and 61 rows that make 4575 cells

Comment: I've tried to draw about 2000 DIVs with js, and it was veeeeeery slow. What you could do is creating a canvas and drawing the rectangles on it - I guess this is the fastest and the easiest way. But apart from that, it would be useful to know what you want to do exactly, and why. You could also add some code!

Comment: Maybe use CSS gradient background pattern? Depends on the complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved with `canvas`!

I made a `JSON` variable to store the value of all the rectangle and at every resize event I redraw the page.

After may try I have found that instead of use

```
context.rect(posX, posY, width, height);
context.fill();
```

I should use

```
context.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
```

that is much faster and I can render the wole amount of rectangles in about 100 ms with internet explorer and I think that it's pretty amazing.

Answer (score 0):

- Requires jQuery

I Have written a short fiddle which seems quite resopnsive to me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var markup = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        markup.push("<span />");
    }
    $('#container').append(markup.join(""));

});
```

[An example of creating 4000 divs as rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZwpK/)

The question is, what are you exactly trying to do? can you provide the problematic example?

Comment: Note that the question does not have a Jquery tag, nor anything in question implies its use. Perhaps you should indicate that your answer requires Jquery.

Comment: yes, you can draw all the rectangle without problems, but the problem is when you must resize all due to window resize.